# convert loop while with two counters into lambdas java 14

Tags: java, lambda

Hi i've tried to convert this method into a lambda expression

```
List<Integer> euclid(int x, int y){
        int q = 0; int r = x;
        while (r >= y){
            q++; r -= y;
        }
        return Arrays.asList(q, r);
 }
```

with this

`Stream.iterate(18,r -> r >= 6, r -> r -=6 ).count().map(Integer::intValue).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: You mean like `euclid(x, y) -> (q, r)`; a lambda that represents that?

Comment: i mean it's supposed to return a list using procedures of the Stream class for calculating how many times "Y" enter in "X", i think that idea the method is learn how to handle 2 counters

Comment: Ah, then I guess Andy gave you the answer you're searching for. You may want to accept it if is. If not, let him know what might be unclear or misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain the state of the two variables. For example:

```
Stream<List<Integer>> stream = Stream.iterate(
    Arrays.asList(0, x),
    current -> current.get(1) > y,
    current -> Arrays.asList(current.get(0) + 1, current.get(1) - y));
```

Now you need to select just one of these, the last one, with the maximum first element:

```
return stream.max(comparingInt(current -> current.get(0))).get();
```

It would probably be easier to read if you stored/returned the q/r pair in a more meaningful type; but since you want to return a `List<Integer>`, the above would suffice.

---

However, don't try to use streams for this. Use the original code, it's clearer and more efficient.